# List of Semaphores in Java and concurrency

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, concurrency, semaphore

I have an application and in my implementation I need a number of Semaphores. My question is how this works with an ArrayList?

Let's say I have an `ArrayList<Semaphore> semList;` containing a number of Semaphores, if I do semList.get(0).aquire(); will the Semaphore be updated accordingly in the list - in other words, will other threads know that's it has been aquired? I'm uncertain since ArrayList.get() only gets a reference to the object.

Comment: Variables that are objects are always references to the object.

Comment: @NathanHughes Do you have any suggestion on a solution?

Comment: [`Vector`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Vector.html) is thread-safe, as is [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).

Comment: @Turing85 I've looked at CopyOnWriteArrayList, but will this work with semaphores as I intend to here. The Semaphore that aquired won't necessary be aquired when the next thread gets from the List or am I wrong?

Comment: Re, "will this work with semaphores as I intend to here?" The way a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` or a `Vector` or any other kind of container works is completely independent of what you put in the container. Likewise, the way a `Semaphore` works is completely independent of where you happened to find a reference to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"will the Semaphore be updated accordingly in the list"?

Think of it this way: the semaphore is not in the list, the list only stores a reference to the semaphore. If another thread calls `get(0)` it will get a reference to the same semaphore (unless the list has been modified, or there is a data race). So yes, other threads will know that it has been aquired.

If you are modifying the list concurrently then you should use a thread safe list, but if it is initialized and filled once and then not changed and published safely to the other threads then you would be fine using an ArrayList.

I recommend reading the JLS section on the memory model to help understand it better: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5

Answer (score 1):

> will the Semaphore be updated accordingly in the list

Yes, it does not matter whether you reference the semaphore directly or via list.get(0). All threads access the same instance. Assuming the semaphore has one permit left, the next thread that calls the acquire method will get the last permit. The next thread will wait until a permit is released.